Отображение QIcon, хранящихся в ресурсах библиотеки dll / so
Проект Qt 5/6 содержит несколько подключаемых библиотек, которые реализуют некоторый интерфейс. Для оформления используются иконки формата svg. Используются в проекте так:
QIcon(":img/datepicker.svg")

в коде библиотеки используются так:
QIcon(":plgcomponents/img/datepicker.svg")

где в первом случае img - это префикс для иконок ресурсов проекта (exe файла), а во втором - plgcomponents/img - префикс, используемый в ресурсном файле dll. При сборке в Windows все отображается нормально, но в случае сборки в Linux - иконки не отображаются.
Windows

Linux

Такое впечатление, что иконки видны только те, которые находятся только в ресурсном файле самого приложения.
Вопрос: Есть ли какие-нибудь идеи как исправить ситуацию, кроме переноса иконок в ресурсы приложения?

Как Вы запускаете приложение? Из Creator'a или exe файл?

@eugesh Под Win - и из под Creator и так - все работает. В Lin - только исполняемый

А у Вас dll - это плагин? Он точно подгружается?
А из Creator'a под Линуксом все хорошо?
По идее, если Вы компилируете ресурсы в elf файл, то ничего, кроме exe файла и библиотеки плагина не нужно.

@eugesh, dll - это просто библиотека, а не созданный средствами Qt плагин. Детальный разбор приводит меня к выводу, что в моем cmake проекте при сборке не указывается link что в бинарник следует включить ресурсы, находящиеся в списке проекта. Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться где и как накосячил.

Хм. Решение проблемы оказалось простым. Файл ресурсов res.qrc лежал в подпапке относительно исходного кода. Т.е. код в папке src, а файл ресурсов src/resource/res.qrc. Стоило его перенести на уровень выше - проблема разрешилась сама собой.
Чертов Хогвартс! ))))
